# Kernel Oops does not show callstack

Tags: linux, debian, kernel-panic

I have an Sipeed Lichee RV86 which is a RISC-V computer and I run Debian on that.

At my last boot, I see a kernel Oops:

```
[    8.674209] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    8.709804] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address ffffffdf809fb520
[    8.739143] Oops [#1]
[    8.741708] Modules linked in: xt_time xt_multiport xt_mark xt_mac xt_limit xt_comment xt_TCPMSS xt_LOG uvcvideo videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops iptable_filter ipt_REJECT fuse
[    8.759563] CPU: 0 PID: 102 Comm: udevadm Not tainted 5.4.61 #154
[    8.766385] sepc: ffffffe000308dc8 ra : ffffffe000308818 sp : ffffffe01c37bdc0
[    8.774486]  gp : ffffffe0008f5a3c tp : ffffffe01e868000 t0 : 0000003fffc777a0
[    8.782586]  t1 : 0000003fffc777a0 t2 : 000000000000000a s0 : ffffffe01c37bde0
[    8.790687]  s1 : 0000000000000004 a0 : ffffffdf809fb498 a1 : ffffffe01c3fc200
[    8.798786]  a2 : 0000000000000004 a3 : 0000000000000004 a4 : ffffffe01c247900
[    8.806887]  a5 : ffffffe000308dbe a6 : ffffffe01c22e990 a7 : 0000000000000000
[    8.814987]  s2 : ffffffe01c247000 s3 : ffffffe01c3fc200 s4 : fffffffffffffff2
[    8.823087]  s5 : ffffffe01c37be98 s6 : ffffffe01c247020 s7 : 0000003fd19152c8
[    8.831189]  s8 : 0000002ad889fa78 s9 : 0000000000000006 s10: 0000002b0bd62480
[    8.839287]  s11: 0000003fffc77aa8 t3 : 0000003fd17911f8 t4 : 000000000000000f
[    8.847387]  t5 : 0000000000000001 t6 : 0000000000040000
[    8.853333] sstatus: 0000000200000120 sbadaddr: ffffffdf809fb520 scause: 000000000000000d
[    9.183428] ---[ end trace 5cfafc85a5ad65b2 ]---
[    9.190368] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): re-mounted. Opts: discard
[    9.605062] systemd-journald[98]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
```

The problem is, that on amd64 machines, I normally get a callstack for a kernel oops. So I can see what binaries/libraries/modules/functions are involved.

On the riscv machine, I just get one address that is bad, but no call stack.

It does say PID 102, but that process is not alive at the moment, so I can't map that to a binary.

How do I proceed to investigate this crash?

**OS**: Debian GNU/Linux bookworm/sid

**kernel**: 5.4.61

**Arch**: riscv64

Comment: This is worth asking in the LKML.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks. I must say, they made Oops investigation really hard. For starters, all the doc sources: *Don't post your oops report before you have checked linux/Documentation/oops-tracing.txt, the relevant paragraphs in linux/README, the ksymoops C program in linux/scripts/ksymoops which has another README, and the gdb man and info pages* Seriously?

Comment: Dismiss this, just send an email.